# Gcloudignore file is not respected during deployment to App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

`gcloud app deploy` keeps uploading all files in source directory, although I have explicitly excluded them using a `.gcloudignore` file. For example, the virtual environment folder `env` is uploaded, which is causing an error because the deployment contains more then 10,000 files then.

I am working under Windows 10 with Python 3.7 and gcloud SDK version 251.0.0. I tried both the beta and the normal version of `gcloud app deploy`.

The `.gcloudignore` file contains just the following:

```
  .gcloudignore
  # If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or
  # files from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line below:
  .git
  .gitignore
  #!include:.gitignore
```

I can see in the outputs with `--verbosity=info` flag that it recognized the `.gcloudignore` file, but then it uploads the `env` folder to Cloud Storage. I would expect this folder to be skipped. Git works as expected.

Comment: I think you are mixing concepts and files. `.gitignore` is for Git repositories, to ignore files, and [`.gcloudignore`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app#ignoring_files) is for ignoring files on the deployment to App Engine. Can you show us your `gcloudignore` file?

Comment: @Mangu thx, this was a typo. I edited the question accordingly

Comment: can you add your `.gitignore` file to the post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "include" everything ignored by your `.gitignore` file in your `.gcloudignore` file by adding the following line:

```
#!include:.gitignore
```

If your `.gitignore` file is already ignoring the `env` directory, this will cause `gcloud` to ignore it as well (and every other file that git is ignoring).

Comment: Yes, you are right @Dustin. The weird thing is that I also tried explicitly including the `env` folder in `.gcloudignore` and it did not work. Anyway, I just worked around the problem by moving `env` and other folders one level up in the directory tree.

Comment: That line isn't commented, it's 'comment syntax' and will actually copy the content of the .gitignore file in your .gcloudignore file when you use it. The hashtag is part of it and does NOT mean 'commented' here.

Answer (score 2):

Your **.gcloudignore file contains two leading spaces on each line which are not allowed**.

These spaces are copied from the documentation so many people will be facing this issue.
See the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) (but do not blindly copy from their until they fixed it)